# Eliminar todos los roles asignados a un usuario

Tags: laravel, permisos, users-roles

Estoy usando Sentinel de cartalyst.com, pero en un entorno autónomo fuera de Laravel, aunque las condiciones serían mas o menos las mismas dentro de Laravel, necesito brindar la opción de cambiar de rol a un usuario, pero en ciertas circunstancias el usuario tiene más de un rol y lo que quiero es borrar de una sóla vez todos los posibles roles a los que se haya asignado el usuario, sin tener que hacer un ciclo para preguntar uno a uno y borrar donde aparezca

La sugerencia para hacerlo uno a uno sería:

```
$user = Sentinel::findById($userId);
$role = Sentinel::findRoleByName('Subscribers');
$role->users()->detach($user);
```

Lo que he intentado concretamente es:

```
$user = Sentinel::findById($userId));
$roles = Sentinel::getRoleRepository();
$roles->users()->detach($user);
```

y no devuelve nada.

... Alguna idea?

Answer (score 0):

Simplemente lo que debes de hacer es obtener el usuario y usar el método `detach()`, el cual, si no recibe parámetros borra todos los registros asociados.

```
$user = Sentinel::findById($userId);
$user->roles()->detach();
```

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que envías al método es los roles a los cuales debería estar asignado el usuario podrías utilizar el método sync. Este método lo que hace es sincronizar totalmente las relaciones. Es decir que en caso de que no exista el rol en los roles pasados por parametro y el usuario en ese momento si lo tengo asociado en la base de datos lo eliminara. En caso de que no exista, lo agregara.

[1]: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships (Sección Syncing Associations
)